# SQL: How to select and sum up columns in this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have been looking but not finding my precise case so I try asking here.
There is a query (which I unfortunately may not disclose) that has this structure:

```
WITH MAINRESULT AS
(
   SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE...GROUP BY...
)
SELECT Name, SUM(MAINRESULT.Amount1 * AnotherAmount) AS MySum FROM MAINRESULT
WHERE .....
GROUP BY Name, AnotherAmount
ORDER BY Name
```

Now, I get something like this:

```
**Name**    **MySum**
   A            5
   A            5
   B            1
   C            2
```

But I want to have this result SUM-med up so that I get:

```
**Name**    **MySum**
   A            10
   B             1
   C             2
```

How do I do this by modifying the query struture that I have?
Tried adding a "SELECT FROM" around both the WITH-query parn and the Second SELECT below it but it says I have syntax errors then.

UPDATE:
I had been staring for too long at that Query I missed that the AnotherAmount should not be included in the GROUP BY part. Thanks everyone for pointing it out so quickly!

Comment: Why GROUP BY AnotherAmount?

Comment: @jarlh Sorry, you are right I have updated the question now.

Comment: What you show us has no syntax errors...

Comment: @AndyKorneyev I removed the faulty AnotherAmount in the GroupBy and it seems to work. It is a pretty large query I got a case of code blindness I think for a good while. I shall accept your answer as soon as it allows me to.

Comment: @jarl Yes, the syntax errors appeared only when I tried to make a SELECT FROM ( SELECT ... FROM) around my query above in different ways (as I tried to explain in my question but perhaps it was not so clearly written, sorry about that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to remove `GROUP BY Name, AnotherAmount` and left only `GROUP BY Name` in your query. Otherwise your results being groupped not only by Name but also by some AnotherAmount field - this may cause unexpected result you're getting.